# Object position (line, column) in XML after deserialization .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How can I get position in the original xml file of an xml tag after deserialization into a .NET object using XmlSerializer ?

Here is an example
XML

```
  <ArrayOfAddressDetails>
     <AddressDetails>
       <Number>4</Number>
       <Street>ABC</Street>
       <CityName>Bern</CityName>
     </AddressDetails>
     <AddressDetails>
       <Number>3</Number>
       <Street>ABCD</Street>
       <CityName>Prague</CityName>
     </AddressDetails>
  </ArrayOfAddressDetails>
```

XMLto C# object mapping

```
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class AddressDetails
{
    [XmlElement("Number")]
    public int HouseNo;
    [XmlElement("Street")]
    public string StreetName;
    [XmlElement("CityName")]
    public string City;
}
```

Desired result

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<AddressDetails>));
 var list = serializer.Deserialize(@"C:\Xml.txt") as List<AddressDetails>;

 // this is what I would like to do

 // getting information to origin of the property City of the 2nd object in the list
 var position = XmlSerializerHelper.GetPosition(o => list[1].City, @"C:\Xml.txt");

 // should print "starts line=10, column=8"
 Console.WriteLine("starts line={0}, column={1}", position.Start.Line, position.Start.Column);

 // should print "ends line=10, column=35"
 Console.WriteLine("ends line={0}, column={1}", position.End.Line, position.Start.Column);

 // should print "type=XmlElement, name=CityName, value=Prague"
 Console.WriteLine("xml info type={0}, name={1}, value={2}", position.Type, position.Name, position.Value);
```

Comment: I have the same question. Did you find a solution in the mean time? If yes, I’d really like to know, please post it.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have not found any solution. :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another, more simple approach: Let the deserializer do the work.

- Add `LineInfo` and `LinePosition` properties to all classes for which you would like to have position information:

  ```
  [XmlRoot("Root")]
  public class AddressDetails
  {
      [XmlAttribute]
      public int LineNumber { get; set; }

      [XmlAttribute]
      public int LinePosition { get; set; }
      ...
  }
  ```

  This of course can be done by subclassing.
- Load an `XDocument` with `LoadOptions.SetLineInfo`.
- Add `LineInfo` and `LinePosition` attributes to all elements:

  ```
  foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants())
  {
       var li = (IXmlLineInfo) element;
       element.SetAttributeValue("LineNumber", li.LineNumber);
       element.SetAttributeValue("LinePosition", li.LinePosition);
   }
  ```
- Deserializing will populate `LineInfo` and `LinePosition`.

Cons:

- Line information only for elements that are deserialized as class, not for simple elements, not for attributes.
- Need to add attributes to all classes.

Comment: I'm wondering if a better solution might be to use a deserializer that you can modify the source code for, and build this support right into the deserializer. There are several C# XML serializer/deserializer projects on CodeSource, if I remember right. Or maybe something from the Mono project?

Comment: @RenniePet This is one of the approaches I considered. I did not find such a (de)serializer – maybe I did not search at the right places?

Comment: For unrelated reasons I did a bit of research into this several years ago, and ended up writing my own serializer/deserializer from scratch. (It's a mess - don't ask. But it's MY mess. :-) From my notes from back then this link still exists today: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15646/A-Deep-XmlSerializer-Supporting-Complex-Classes-En Good luck.

Comment: Another one: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/455861/Serialize-Deserialize-any-object-to-an-XML-file

Comment: @RenniePet Thank you! The projects to which you linked all take objects and create _special_ XML, and then are able to convert that special XML back. In contrast, we would need a “convert arbitrary XML to appropriate objects”. If I understand it correctly, they are only indirectly useful for this question, they can be a start for creating my own Yet One More Deserializer Project - but currently I do not have the time to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several approaches. Two of them:

- Implement `IXmlSerializable`. In principle this would work, but then one would have to implement the *complete* deserialization mechanism.
- Deserialize using an `XmlReader`, save a reference to that `XmlReader` at some `static` location, and in the constructor of classes that are deserialized, access that `XmlReader` and retrieve line and position information. Cons: `static`; relatively complicated.

I did not find a way to get more information than start line and position, but honestly, that’s enough for my use case.

Currently I think I will use the following approach.

- Load the XML file with line information:

  ```
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
  ```
- To all elements in `xdoc`, add a new attribute (e.g. `NewId`) that allows to identify the elements, e.g. give the first element a 0, the second a 1, etc.
- Make sure all classes that are deserialized (in your case `AddressDetails`) will have such a `NewId`, e.g.:

  ```
      [XmlAttribute]
      public int NewId { get; set; }
  ```

  This can be done by deriving from a common base class, and even when `xsd.exe` is used to create the classes, this is possible because it will create all classes as `partial` (e.g. a `partial class foo : MyBaseClassElement { }` needs to be added somewhere for all classes).
- After deserializing, for each element that has been deserialized as a class object, the `XElement` from which it has been deserialized can be looked up using `NewId`. (To speed up the look up, one can use a `List<XElement>` that contains all `XElement` such that `NewId` is the index in that list.)
- Casting the `XElement` to `IXmlLineInfo` will give line and position information.
- For elements that have not been deserialized as a class object (e.g. `Number` in your example) and for attributes, first look up the `XElement` that contains a `NewId` (e.g. `AdressDetails`), then query the element’s or attribute’s line information:

  ```
  XElement element = ...;
  XNode descendant = element.Descendants(childElementOrAttributetName).FirstOrDefault();
  return descendant as IXmlLineInfo;
  ```

Cons:

- Memory usage.
- Need to add attribute to all classes.