# Line number and position information when deserializing from XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I’m reading an XML file by deserializing using classes generated by `xsd.exe`.

Is there a way to get line number and position information in the XML file for an object created by the deserializing?

*Background:*

The XML contains a number of `foo` elements that reference “items” in another file using some kind of ID. An error message like `Cannot find item with ID 4711 in file bar.txt` is ok, but I’d prefer a `myfile.xml(288, 12) : Cannot find item with ID 4711 in file bar.txt`.

That is, the XML file contains something like:

```
...
<foo>
  <ID>4711</ID>
  ...
</foo>
....
```

`xsd.exe` creates a class `foo`, and deserializing will return an object of type `foo` that has `myFoo.ID == 4711`.

To create such an error message, I need to know the line number and position for the XML from which `myFoo` was created, or even better, for the property `myFoo.ID`.

Comment: Check out the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementeventargs.linenumber(v=vs.110).aspx
Also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnodeeventargs.aspx 
it might help you.

Comment: @KamranShahid I don’t know how this could help me. `XMLSerializer` provides events only for _unknown_ entities.

Comment: We might need your full class,xml and your current de-serializing code

Comment: @KamranShahid I cannot provide "full class" etc. because the schema alone has several hundred lines. The de-serializing code is trivial. You might want to use the example in the article about [XmlSerializer.Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx), and btw it does not matter which schema/classes are used.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173213/object-position-line-column-in-xml-after-deserialization-net

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object position (line, column) in XML after deserialization .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173213/object-position-line-column-in-xml-after-deserialization-net)