# C# Net core XML deserialization or how to get indexes of rows in file

Tags: c#, xml, validation, .net-core, deserialization

Please tell me if it is possible after the deserialization of the XML file to get line numbers, from which values for specific properties were taken. Or are there other ways? I need to get the line numbers in the file where errors occurred (there are paths to tags with errors, for example yml_catalog/offers/offer[ 1 ]/price)

I have here such a model, in which there are values from tags:

```
[XmlRoot("yml_catalog")]
public class YMLCatalog
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Time of generation
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [XmlAttribute("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shop
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [ValidateObject]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "shop")]
    public Shop Shop { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Sale point
/// </summary>
public class Shop
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shop name
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Company name
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [XmlElement("company")]
    public string Company { get; set; }
    ... etc
}
```

ValidationObject - This is an attribute for recursive validation via Validator.TryValidateObject(context,[my empty model object],[list of ValidationResult - error list], true);

*Finding line numbers with regular expressions is not suitable for me, since the files can be very large and have a huge number of errors, and I only have error messages and paths to them*

[Example of file](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ke8xH3TUuDCUhdzCRGWYlGZ2LtbNUOqpBs4pPiEsU6U/edit) with an error in the first tag 'offer' (tag price is empty)

UPD - [This solution is not suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173213/object-position-line-column-in-xml-after-deserialization-net). There is no support for simple elements and attributes!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173213/object-position-line-column-in-xml-after-deserialization-net

Comment: @mjwills to get error list with line numbers for user.

Comment: @IvanZaruba thanks, not bad :) But I'm interested in more options)

Comment: @IvanZaruba And I need the positions not only of the objects of classes, but also of the usual properties, for example, [XmlElement] public string SomeTag {get;set;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done via LINQ. If you want to get information about a node with a number and a position, you should use the XmlDocument method instead of the SelectNode method, use XPathSelectElement, and bring it to the interface IXmlLineInfo

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
var node = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//shop/offers/offer[1]/price");
var lineNumber =  ((IXmlLineInfo)node).LineNumber;
```

Comment: Amazing... First you say "UPD - This solution is not suitable" then you post the code that was mentioned in that "unsuitable solution".